# Recommended model to analyze relationship with aggregate rate

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, python, aggregation

In order to analyze the relationship between some independent variables and a binary dependent variable, it is standard to use logistic regression, which allows us to model the probability of the independent variable equalling 1 conditioned on the independent variables.

However, what is the standard model used for aggregate rates? For instance, take some cross-country data, where the dependent variable is national unemployment rate and where we do not have micro-data? Logistic regression cannot be used because the variable is not binary, and similarly linear regression does not seem to be a good fit because the predicted value must lie between 0 and 1.

What statistical technique would you recommend for this?

I have researched a little on solutions, but have been failing for now:

- Instead of the rate, I can use count data. However, my data is
  unemployment rates by country, so I have very high counts
- Poisson and Negative Binomial models fail to converge
- I've seen it recommended to use a Gaussian GLM with a log link function. What is the point of this?

I'm interested in your recommended approach

Comment: The second one is the best if you can "breaking up". If cannot, use the first one.

Comment: Yes, it's easy for me to find the counts of successes and failures. However, once I have this, I am still unsure what to use. Linear regression is not appropriate for count data as far as I know. Poisson regression would not work because in my data mean != variance. I've tried negative binomial, which seems like a good idea for counts, but it fails to converge. I've read that it can be a good idea to use a Gaussian GLM with a log link function, but I don't understand why it makes sense. Would you have any insights on this?

Comment: Then use the logistic regression.

Comment: How can I apply logistic regression to non-binary data? Rates are between 0 and 1, counts are >= 0

Comment: Depending on the what software you will use. But it should have no problem to fit logistic regression.

Comment: I've never seen logistic regression applied to a rate (continuous between 0 and 1) or to counts. Would you have an example at hand?

Comment: Not apply to rate. Apply to the number of unemployment and number of employments. This is the reason for breaking up.

Comment: [this paper uses logit](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/7894008/8033722/20170519-111211_Q2016_paper_flows_-_final.docx.pdf/c09d9c33-4d8c-43bd-a2b0-80926fd4ac1e)

Answer (score 0):

You can use logistic regression with event/trial syntax or poisson loglinear regression with an offset parameter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/343161)